# WooCommerce: How to Disable/Enable Cash on Delivery Gateway for specific Currency?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency, code-snippets

I found this code regarding disabling payment methods based on Countries, is there any way to disable payment methods based on "Currency"?

```
    /**
    * @snippet       WooCommerce Disable Payment Gateway for a Specific Country
    * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
    * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=164
    * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
    * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.5.7
    * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
    */

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_payment_gateway_disable_country' );

    function bbloomer_payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
      if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
       if ( isset( $available_gateways['authorize'] ) && WC()->customer->get_billing_country() <> 'US' ) { 
        unset( $available_gateways['authorize'] );
      } else {
          if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && WC()->customer->get_billing_country() == 'US' ) {
             unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
     }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
 }
```

I only want Cash on Delivery option to show if the currency selected is in PKR. I am using the Currency Switcher for WooCommerce plugin to switch the currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the below code in your current active theme **functions.php** file.

```
function disable_cod_for_pkr_filter_gateways($gateway_list)
{
  //return if admin
  if ( is_admin() ) 
    return $available_gateways;

  //check currency
  $currency = get_woocommerce_currency(); 

  if ($currency == 'PKR')
  {
     unset($gateway_list['cod']);
  }

  return $gateway_list;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_cod_for_pkr_filter_gateways', 1);
```

I hope it will help you.